# Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a script in jmeter . However , I am facing the below error

Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

It says , connection is refused to that site. But,  I am able to open the site manually.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you're sitting behind corporate proxy. Browser uses proxy to connect to the Internet and JMeter doesn't.

If this is the case you can "tell" JMeter to use the same proxy server as browser does via the following command-line arguments:

```
-H, --proxyHost <argument>
    Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
-P, --proxyPort <argument>
    Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
-N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
    Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
-u, --username <argument>
    Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
-a, --password <argument>
    Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
```

See

- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) article for more command-line tips and tricks
- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) - all command-line keys JMeter can understand.